# Where can I ask this question about why we use cans instead of boxes?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/64359/41540) question on Seasoned Advice a few minutes ago, but was shot down.  Unfortunately, the mod there couldn't provide me any better place on SE to ask.  So maybe one of you can.  **Where on Stack Exchange can I ask the question I've linked?**

I've reproduced it below:

> This question is ostensibly about canned food or drinks, but it really applies to anything sold in a more or less cylindrical package (paint, medicine, WD-40, etc.).  Hence I'd really like to understand this in terms of more than just food.  This is the most appropriate place I could think of to ask, but if this can be moved elsewhere I'd be happy to do so.
>
> We buy containers of food or drinks caring less about the *dimensions* of a package and more about the *volume* of it (i.e. what it can actually hold), even if we're not always aware of it.  But with high school algebra, you can easily show that a box of volume `V` will have a smaller surface area (and thus need less metal, plastic, etc. to manufacture) than a cylinder (can, bottle, etc.) of identical volume.
>
> **Given that it uses less materials to make a box than a can of the same volume, why are "canned" foods or similar not sold in small boxes?**

Comment: Try [Sustainability](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) SE?

Comment: metal is made in sheets, its easier to cut a sheet to make a tube than to cut and have to make 3 folds

Comment: Think about trying to create a box that can hold 12oz of coke, resist shipping damage, keep the product in sellable condition for over a year, drinkable condition for 5-10 years, be easily opened and used, and be cheaper to manufacture than an aluminum can.  If you come up with something, congrats--you're rich.